# Segue from TableView into another Tableview using gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, swift-protocols

I have FirstTableView (TableView) which is populated by cells that have an image and label. If users tap the label, I want to segue into another tableview (SecondTableView), which will use the label from the previous tableview as a path(foldername) to search for images within that folder and display them as cells.

I have bits and pieces of the code written together, but I'm not quite sure where to pass the  `perform segue` and `prepare for segue` functions.

Here is the extension of my FirstTableViewController, which populate the cells of the FirstTableView:

### FirstTableView

```
extension FirstTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
   
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataCells.count
    }
        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let folderCell = dataCells[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstTableCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
        cell.setCell(cell:folderCell)
        
        return cell
        
        }
}
```

Here is the code for the `FirstTAbleViewCell`. Notice that I've created the `UITapGestureRecognizer` constant and a `protocol`.  If the `FolderLabel` is clicked, I want to segue into the next tableview.

`func setCell` is just the function to populate the FirstTableViews.

### FirstTableViewCells

```
import UIKit

protocol LabelCellDelegate {
    func func1(sender:Any)
}

    
    
    class FirstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
        @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var FolderLabel: UILabel!
        
        var delegate: LabelCellDelegate?
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            
            FolderLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector(("handleTap:")))
            recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            self.FolderLabel.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
        
        func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
            delegate!.func1(sender: self)
        }
        func setCell (cell : FolderCell){
            self.ImageView.image = cell.image
            self.FolderLabel.text = cell.label
        }
    }
```

Next is the `SecondTableViewController`.
Somehow, after the tap of the cell from the FirstTableView I want to get the label name that was tapped, and use that name as a directory to search.
Grab all the images within the directory and display them as images in cells in SecondTableView. I'm not quite sure where I should be calling the `gesture` function and which TableViewController should be the delegate of the cell protocol.

### SecondTableView

```
import UIKit

class SecondTableViewController: UIViewController {
    var Imagefiles: [String] //Imagefiles String. This are all images from tapped folder label. 
    var CellObjects: [folderCell] // Cellobjects to fill the cells. contains images and image names.
    
     // need to get folder name from FirstTableViewCell how?
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageFiles = getImageObjects(folder: Foldercell) //how to get access to folderCell???????
        cellObjects = createArray(imageFiles: imageFiles)
        }
    
    func getImageObjects(folder: FolderCell) -> imageFiles: String {
        //FUNCTION To search tapped label and grab all image file paths. 
    
    
    func createArray(imageFiles: string)-> tempArray: [folderCell]{
         //We use this function to take the image files from above function and 
         //create cell objects to populate our cells 
       //in SecondTableView

        
    
   
        }
      }
    
    
    
}
    
}



  extension ViewController: LabelCellDelegate{
        func1(folderLabel : String) {
        return folderLabel
        
        
        }
    }

extension LablesTableView:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return CellObjects.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellFolderObject = folderObjects[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondCell") as! LabelCell
         let folderCell = CellObjects[indexPath.row]

        cell.setCell(cell: folderCell)
     
        return cell
```

As you can see, I haven't called `perform segue` and `prepare for segue`. I'm not sure where I should be calling them.
I'm also unsure about where the delegate to the gesture protocol should be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `cellForRowAt` set

```
cell.delegate = self
```

//

then inside this delegate function of the VC ( conform to the protocol `LabelCellDelegate` )

```
extension FirstTableViewController:LabelCellDelegate {
   func func1(sender: FirstTableViewCell) {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender:sender.FolderLabel.text!)
  }
}
```

//

the VC method is triggered from here

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
  delegate!.func1(sender: self)
}
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if let secondController = segue.destination as? SecondTableViewController {
     secondController.sendedStr = sender as! String
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How about passing the data? I want to pass the label of the cell selected.

Comment: If sender is FirstTableViewCell (`func func1(sender: FirstTableViewCell)`) I get `does not conform to protocol` error message. If I change it to `any` the error seems to be go away.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference. I will have to take care of another error (which errors after build), before I can see the results.

Comment: change protocol method to **func func1(sender:FirstTableViewCell)**